# How to loop through groups in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

From these dataframes:

```
 library(pracma)
 df1 <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(20,0.4,0.2), seq(0,200,by=10)))
 df2 <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(30,0.6,0.25), seq(0,270,by=9)))
 df1$Source = "df1"
 df2$Source = "df2"
 df_combined = rbind(df1, df2)
  res <- (data.frame(X2 = detrend(df_combined$X2[which(df_combined$X2 <= 1000)]), X1=      
  detrend(df_combined$X1 [which(df_combined$X2 <= 1000)])))
```

You see that this will consider all values in X1 and X2 but I need to this per group listed in source.

I prefer the output to have the same format that df_combined

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `dplyr`, there is a nice function `group_by()`

```
library(dplyr)

res <- df_combined %>%
    filter(X2 <= 1000) %>%
    group_by(Source) %>%
    mutate(
        X2 = detrend(X2),
        X1 = detrend(X1)
    )
```

Comment: thanks. I see that you mutate.I do not want to mutate in df_combined  but to have a new one  like df_combined2  with same format of df_combined.

Comment: In fat in my real data, the size of X1 and X2 of the output might be different from the original size and thus i got the error in mutate